# How can I connect HDMI out from an android setup box to a android tablet to see the setup box screen?

Tags: android, hdmi

I want to connect an android setup box HDMI out to an android tablet to see the screen of the setup box in the tablet. Here I want to interface an android setup box with the android tablet, so that I can test my android app from setup box to a handy tablet. Is there is any hardware connector or any android app to read the HDMI signal from outside???

Comment: android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a tablet with HDMI IN for that, but I think this feature does not exists.
So you can't.

But you can use remote desktop or screen share applications to see what the box is displaying.